# BlackListing Command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm using discord.js to create a discord bot, but I'm kind of new to javascript and more used to C#. I'm Having a Problem with my bot, I'm trying to blacklist words and I was able to do that, but I'm experiencing a bug, and when I send a command with a blacklisted word; the command executes but I don't want that to happen so I need it to read the command and check if it has a blacklisted word in the command content.

```js
 if(config.FILTER_LIST.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))){

        const listEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("EBE306")
        .setTitle(`**BlackListed**`)
        .setDescription(`**This Word blacklisted**`)
        .setFooter(`Reaper`)
        message.channel.send(listEmbed);
      
        function dohelp() {
            const helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("EBE306")
            .setTitle(`Help Menu`)
            .setDescription(``)
            .setFooter(`Reaper`)
            message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
          }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your code is structured something like this:

```js
client.on('message', message =>{
       if(config.FILTER_LIST.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))){

        const listEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("EBE306")
        .setTitle(`**BlackListed**`)
        .setDescription(`**This Word blacklisted**`)
        .setFooter(`Reaper`)
        message.channel.send(listEmbed);
      
        function dohelp() {
            const helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("EBE306")
            .setTitle(`Help Menu`)
            .setDescription(``)
            .setFooter(`Reaper`)
            message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
          }

    }
// do the command.
}
```

And in that case, you just need to add a return statement (see code below) at the end of the if statement.
If I misunderstood your question please leave a comment below.

```js
client.on('message', message =>{
if(config.FILTER_LIST.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word))){

        const listEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
        .setColor("EBE306")
        .setTitle(`**BlackListed**`)
        .setDescription(`**This Word blacklisted**`)
        .setFooter(`Reaper`)
        message.channel.send(listEmbed);
      
        function dohelp() {
            const helpEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
            .setColor("EBE306")
            .setTitle(`Help Menu`)
            .setDescription(``)
            .setFooter(`Reaper`)
            message.channel.send(helpEmbed);
          }
          return;
    }
// run the command.
}
```

Comment: I tired that and the command still went through i just want it were it says word had been blacklist not the help menu here is a pic of me trying it https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/774057854788567050/778661338070515732/unknown.png

Comment: You will have to show us more code, for example where and how you call the command...